Are algebras with rational structures dense in varieties of real Lie nilpotent algebras?
One says that a real nilpotent Lie algebra has $\mathbb Q$-structure if it has a basis with rational structure constants. It is well known that there are nilpotent Lie algebras without $\mathbb Q$-structures. I am trying to answer the following questions:

Are nilpotent Lie algebras with $\mathbb Q$-structures dense among nilpotent Lie algebras (in Euclidean topology)?
Another related question. Let $L$ be a real finite dimensional linear space with a fixed basis $e_1,\dots,e_2$. Let $C_{i,j}^k$ be the structure constant of some nilpotent Lie algebra structure on $L$. Is it true that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a nilpotent Lie algebra with rational structure constants $\smash{\tilde C}_{i,j}^k$ such that $|C_{i,j}^k-\smash{\tilde C}_{i,j}^k|<\epsilon$.

It is clear that 2. implies 1. Also the answer on 2. is "Yes" for positively graded nilpotent Lie algebras. Probably, the question is some how related with Rigid nilpotent Lie algebras. Indeed, if there is a rigid nilpotent Lie algebra without $\mathbb Q$-structure, then the answer on 1. es negative.
Added. As YCor comented, the question Q1 and Q2 is actually equivalent….
My motivation is the following theorem (due to Malcev): A nilpotent simplyconnected Lie group $G$ has a lattice if and only its Lie algebra has a $\mathbb Q$-structure. Moreover, for every $\epsilon>0$ one can find a lattice $L$ such that $O_\epsilon(L)=G$. As $L$ is residually finite it allows, in a sense, approximate $G$ by finite groups. If the answer on my question were positive any sympliconnected nilpotent Lie group would have an approximate lattice and would be approximal by finite groups (in a some weaker sense)….

Why is it true that 2 has a positive answer in the positively graded case?

What is the difference between Q1 and Q2? is it that in Q1 you're not requiring the approximating Lie algebra to be nilpotent?

@YCor. In graded case the Jacobi equation converted to consecutive linear equations. So, the solution does not depend of the field. So, I can write a Q-solution, conserving the grading. Am I right?

In Q1 I also suppose approximating Lie algebra to bi nilpotent. The difference is that may be I have to change the basis to get a real structure constants. I will make the corresponding edit...

I really don't see the difference between Q1 and Q2.  If you have another basis for which Q2 holds, just approximate the change of basis with rational ones.

@YCor Well, yes, you are right. I was stubborn...

For "nilpotent Lie" replaced by "associative commutative unital" this is wide open, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.11997 for some recent progress. I would expect that also the nilpotent Lie case is open.

What is $O_\epsilon(L)$?

I'd expect the answer to be negative. Possibly a close look at filiform Lie algebras of dimension 9 or 10 could be helpful.

@LSpice $O_\epsilon(L)$ is the union of $\epsilon$-balls centered in points of $L$ (for some Euclidean distance on the group $G$).
